# Is $\log(-1)$ equal to $-\log(-1)$

Tags: complex-numbers, logarithms

I thought it should be because if the logarithmic identities hold then, 
$$-\log(-1)=\log(-1^{-1})=\log(-1)$$
But $\log(-1)=i*\pi$ and  $-\log(-1)=-i*\pi$

Comment: In complex analysis, logarithm functions are multivalued, so one must be more careful.

Comment: Sigh. This has been covered umpteen times. Picking as a duplicate...

Answer (score 4):

The principal branch of the logarithm is $\log(-1)=\pi i$, which doesn't satisfy the identity you're looking for: $-\pi i\neq\pi i$.

The multi-valued logarithm is $\mathrm{Log}(-1)=\pi i + 2\pi i\mathbb Z$, which does satisfy the identity:
$$-(\pi i + 2\pi i\mathbb Z)=\pi i + 2\pi i\mathbb Z.$$

Answer (score 2):

In complex numbers, for a complex number $z=re^{i\theta}$,
$$
\ln(z)=\ln(r)+i(\theta+2\pi k)
$$
where $k$ is any integer.  (This is called a multi-valued function because there is more than one output for a given input, namely all the possible values for a given $k$.)

In your situation, $r=1$ and $\theta=\pi$.  But note that $-\pi$ and $\pi$ differ by $2\pi$, so you're just getting two values that are part of the same  multi-valued output.  So you get $i(\pi+2\pi 0)=i\pi$ and $i(\pi+2\pi(-1))=-i\pi$.

Answer (score 0):

Logarithmic identities that you learnt hold for "positive" numbers only.

Comment: Many of the identities do extend to complex numbers, perhaps with a little care.

Comment: For most identities and given specific numbers you can usually chose a specific branch of the logarithm such that the equality holds for those numbers.